# How to run command promt command while running angular app?

Tags: angular, typescript, google-chrome, kiosk, kiosk-mode

I want to run 2 cmd commands when a user hits the URL.

```
taskkill /IM chrome.exe /F
start chrome.exe --kiosk -tab "www.url.com"
```

These are the 2 commands.
Is it possible to do so with typescript or anything else in Angular?

Comment: Why on Earth do you want to do this? What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: my app needs to run in kiosk mode but doing manually is not the best way to do i guess as this is a online test portal

Comment: Could you include this in your original question then, to give more context? Where is this running? Do you have control of the computer it's running on? Or is this on any user's computer? It'd be a bit dangerous being able to run arbitrary shell commands from a web page, now, wouldn't it?

Answer (score 3):

Firstly, what you're doing is *weird*, which should be enough of a signal that it's probably a bad idea, and that there's almost certainly a better way.

In any case, though, you're thinking at the wrong layer: Typescript is a language, Angular is a framework; neither inherently provides any concept of interacting with the command line—they're designed to run in a web browser (where of course you don't want random websites you visit to be able to kill your web browser). There are frameworks for running Javascript (and thus Typescript) in a non-browser context (e.g. Node.js), but that doesn't sound like a fit for your question.

This means you need to figure out some place to deploy your privileged code *outside* the web browser:

- If this is designed to run as a kiosk, you could build a desktop application that hosts Chromium or another web browser in it (e.g. using [CEF](https://bitbucket.org/chromiumembedded/cef)) instead of running in a conventional web browser, which allows you to invoke desktop code from Javascript (and thus from Typescript or Angular). This solution probably defeats the point of what you're trying to do, though, since it would replace the need for running Chrome in kiosk mode.
- You can create a standalone desktop app that runs whatever you want and also registers a custom protocol handler (e.g. `my-app://`), which you can then invoke from Chrome (note that by default Chrome will show a security prompt before running your code if you do this, but if you control the target device—and I hope you do given what you're trying to do—there are ways to disable the prompt for your registered protocol).
- You can build a desktop app that runs a web server in the background and (bearing in mind cross-site restrictions) make a request from that known URL. Your server app could then interpret the request to run arbitrary code (e.g. quitting the app). This is the method [Zoom was recently chastised for implementing](https://www.theverge.com/2019/7/10/20689644/apple-zoom-web-server-automatic-removal-silent-update-webcam-vulnerability).

Be aware that in most of these scenarios untrusted sites could similarly invoke this code, so bear that in mind during design.